# WPF DragDrop with ctrl key down

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement a drag drop functionality in `wpf` form. The aim is to implement make a copy of usercontrol by dragging it (similar to windows 7 folder copy using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + `Mouseleftbutton` drag and drop). The drop works fine when the ctrl key is not down, but when the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key is down the drop event is not getting fired. How can i detect a drop when <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key is down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to detect key presses to accomplish what you're after. It all depends on what the value of the `(DragEventArgs).AllowedEffects` property. This is initially set when you call the `DragDrop.DoDragDrop` method:

```
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dragSource, data, DragDropEffects);
```

Here, the `DragDropEffects` property represents an enumeration of type `DragDropEffects`. If you set this to `DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move`, then you *should* be able to move *or* copy (by holding down the `Ctrl` key):

```
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dragSource, data, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
```

Now in one of the drag and drop handlers that receives a parameter of type `DragEventArgs`, you *should* see that the `(DragEventArgs).AllowedEffects` property will have the value that you set in the `DragDrop.DoDragDrop` method. It just remains for you to set the  `(DragEventArgs).Effects` property to the same value to 'allow' both operations to take place when the user releases the mouse button.